# Parallelize data preparation with tensorflow and keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, training-data, tensorflow2.x

I'm training an LSTM model on GPU using Tensorflow Keras. Before training starts when calling `model.fit()` it takes about 30 minutes to start training process. I think in this period its preparing data using one core of CPU. Am I correct? and if yes how can I parallelize this data preparation process, using multiple cores?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `tf.data.Dataset()` for preparing your data, you can exploit  some parameters while preparing the dataset.

1. For example, in your `.map()` function, set the `num_parallel_calls` parameter to `num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE`; in this way it will allow your program to automatically choose the number of CPU cores for the dataset preparation.
2. The speed can also be improved if you use the `.batch().shuffle()`
   in this order, rather than `shuffle().batch()` in this order. In the first situation, you take a batch of your dataset and shuffle the elements inside it; in the second case, you `batch()` on your dataset after the entire dataset is shuffled. One can easily see that shuffling an enormous dataset would lead to much more time spent rather than batching and shuffling in this order.
3. Let us see another case(related to the actual training process)(not your case as the dataset preparation is
   very time-consuming in your situation): the `prefetch()` operation.
   In this case, the GPU is not idling while waiting for the CPU to
   fetch another batch of data. Practically, when the backpropagation
   has finished updating the weights after a batch, the GPU immediately
   consumes another batch of data. For simplicity purposes, also set its value to `tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE`.